# Canvas' verticalScrollPosition cannot be changed in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a weird problem with verticalScrollPosition in Flex.
I have a content Canvas and a wrapper Canvas. The content is large (5000px X 5000px), the wrapper is 800px X 800px.

```
public var wrapper:Canvas = new Canvas();
public var content:Canvas = new Canvas();
wrapper.addChild(content);
application.addChild(wrapper);
```

I would like to set the wrapper's scrollbar position dynamically anytime. I can do it by calling its properties:

```
wrapper.verticalScrollPosition = A;
wrapper.horizontalScrollPosition = B;
```

This is working fine. But! If I set a default scrollbar position when the Canvas is complete:

```
wrapper.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function(e:FlexEvent):void{
    wrapper.verticalScrollPosition = DEFAULT_A;
    wrapper.horizontalScrollPosition = DEFAULT_B;
});
```

I can't set the verticalScrollPosition anymore:

```
wrapper.verticalScrollPosition = C;
trace(wrapper.verticalScrollPosition); // Outputs: DEFAULT_A
```

So the problem only exist if I set a default position using 'FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE'.
What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that the unnamed function is being called

Comment: It's called only once when the Canvas is getting ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. I attached the event listener to the child of the wrapper. When I added the listener to the wrapper itself it works.

So lesson I've learnt: always track the topmost ui element's events you have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a horrible workaround - I wait 1 microsecond to set the default state:

```
wrapper.addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function(e:FlexEvent):void{
  setTimeout(
    function():void{wrapper.verticalScrollPosition = DEFAULT_A;},
    1
  );
});
```

I think we can agree it's really ugly. How can I make it better?